# MVC, Swing, Observer Pattern Design Decision

Tags: swing, model-view-controller, architecture, observer-pattern

I am trying to implement a small application using Swing and MVC Design Pattern with MS SQL Server as the backend.
The application starts with a simple login form. Also there are two kinds of roles for the users of the application.

1. Administrator: Can create, delete, modify, view all users plus all the functionality the application provides.
2. Application Users: Can only use the functionality the application provides.

I'm thinking to have two separate Frames i.e. UI for each role.

The main login form/GUI acts as a view, with a Login controller class which registers the view using Observer pattern. The button registers the event, which the controller listens, calls the appropriate DAO to connect to database and verify if the user can log on to the application.
The stored procedure for login returns access_role i.e. either administrator, application user, unknown user or non-authenticated user which is returned through DAO back to Login Controller.

I want to keep the coupling as low as possible, hence the separation of concerns and MVC design with Observer Pattern.

Now my questions are,

1. Should the Login controller decide based on the access_role returned to show either the application user UI or the Administrator UI or should it pass that information back to the Login UI which should initialize the respective GUI ?
2. If the Login Controller should decide which UI to initiate, then it would need to set all listeners as well for the respective GUI? Is that a good design decision or is there a better way of doing this?
3. If the Login Controller passes the access_control back to the Login Form, then that Login Form would have to initialize all the Listeners for the new GUI and instantiate the new GUI as well? Is this better than the controller doing the stuff?
4. Should the UI for Administrator and Application User be JFrame or Dialogs ?

Hoping to hear your views about it.

Best regards,
Kashif Khan

Answer (score 0):

1. I'm not sure if I would want the Login Controller or the Login UI initialize a different part of my application.  In the interest of keeping things decoupled I would want the Login stuff to handle no other function but logging in a user.  It might be a good idea to have like a Application Controller that initializes the Login part of your application and when it authenticates a user pass that message back to it which will decide which GUI needs to be initialized next.
2. As stated in part 1, the the Login Controller should just pass a message back to the Overall Application Controller which will make a decision on which part of the Application needs to be initialized next.
3. It would seem out of scope of the Login Form to handle all of these actions.  The Login form should merely just communicate to the Application controller whether login was successful or not and some basic information about the user so additional information can be gathered as needed from the database on during the next part of initialization.
4. From the JDialog Oracle Documentation "A Dialog window is an independent subwindow meant to carry temporary notice apart from the main Swing Application Window"  This being said you wouldnt want to use Dialogs for your main application.  You could however use a Dialog for the Login form if you chose to and that would be acceptable.

I hope this helps.